# CloudFormation: Access PrivateDnsNamespace as HostedZone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, service-discovery

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicediscovery-privatednsnamespace.html) for `ServiceDiscovery::PrivateDnsNamespace` states that:

> When you create a private DNS namespace, AWS Cloud Map automatically creates an Amazon Route 53 private hosted zone that has the same name as the namespace.

In CloudFormation, is there any way to access the created `HostedZone` (as a `Route53::HostedZone`) so I can add additional `Route53:RecordSet`s to it?

- Is the ID the same?
- Can I include a `Route53::HostedZone` with the same name to get the right ID?
- Is there some other trick?

For example, I'd like to expose my RDS and ElastiCache (Redis) instance at private DNS entries.  I realize this could be the XY problem, but I'm accessing these systems at standard locations in my legacy code and am trying minimize the customization (and thus potential bugs) in my first ECS attempt.

**WARNING:  While AWS Service Discovery strategies can be used to expose services like DB and RDS, there are several qualifications:**

- AWS Service Discovery requires the syntax `<name>.<namespace>` so you can't simply expose the services at `db` and `redis`.  Your best odds for a 'standard' domain is something like `redis.local` and `db.local`.  While `local` is a reserved TLD, there's some hostility to its use.
- [RDS SSL certificates are tied to the RDS domain name](https://github.com/cfn-modules/fargate-service/issues/18#issuecomment-538866514) and [custom SSL certificates are not supported](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=215902) so you can't expose it at `db.<mydomain>.com`.  If you don't use the RDS CNAME, you won't be able to connect to these instances over trusted SSL connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to access the created `HostedZone` in CloudFormation.

Still, if you want to add additional records to this private zone you can use the [`AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicediscovery-service.html) and [`AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Instance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicediscovery-instance.html) resources.

Basically, you need to create one service for your RDS instance and one service for your Redis instance. Then you create instances in your services.

Example for RDS:

```yaml
RDSSDService:
  Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
  Properties:
    DnsConfig:
      DnsRecords:
        - TTL: 60
          Type: CNAME
      NamespaceId:
        Ref: YourNamespace
      RoutingPolicy: WEIGHTED
    Name: my-rds-service # this will become the record name
    NamespaceId:
      Ref: YourNamespace

RDSSDInstance: # If your RDS instance is in the same stack
  Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Instance
  Properties:
    InstanceAttributes:
      AWS_INSTANCE_CNAME:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - YourInstanceLogicalName
          - Endpoint.Address
    ServiceId:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - RDSSDService
        - Id
    InstanceId: # this is optional
      Ref: YourInstanceLogicalName

RDSInstance: # If referencing an existing instance
  Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Instance
  Properties:
    InstanceAttributes:
      AWS_INSTANCE_CNAME: xyz.abc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com # or with Fn::ImportValue
    ServiceId:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - RDSSDService
        - Id
    InstanceId: xyz # this is optional
```

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely XY.  I was working with a template that already used `Route53::RecordSet` so it didn't occur to me to look for the same functionality in the `ServiceDiscovery` namespace.